# Assigning attributes values from a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, attributes, python

I have a large dictionary. I'd like to assign each key value pair to an attribute of a class. Currently I have something along the lines of the snippet below. It works, however it's not pretty. Is there a better way to do this?

Pseudo-python snippet :

```
config = A large dictionary

self.Width  = config['width']
self.Height = config['height']
self.Text   = config['text']
self.Font   = config['font']
etc...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
for key, value in config.iteritems():
    # Customize key here, for example transform 'text_height' to 'TextHeight' or 
    # use 'key.title()' to obtain titlecased keys...
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

You may want to do `key.title()`, but instance attributes are suggested to be all lowercase in python.

Comment: Use `key.title()` to convert 'width' key to 'Width' attribute.

Comment: It may be good to consider what happens in the case of multi-word keys. e.g., should `config['text_height']` be assigned to `self.TextHeight`?

Comment: Darren Yin, I got around that by hard coding the names then converting them to key format using str.lower().

Comment: @Darren:  In that case, OP should just change his config file or attribute names to match.

Comment: quick minor nitpick--the code block comment could be construed to mean that `'text_height'.title() == 'TextHeight'`, when in actuality, `'text_height'.title() == 'Text_Height'`.

Comment: @Darren: Thanks, should be better now.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't care about the titlecase, you could just do:

```
self.__dict__.update(config)
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the class defines `@properties` or custom a `__setattr__` method.

Comment: @GaretJax: I admit - it's a bit of a hack.  ...kind of just threw it out there to see if I'd get flamed or not :)  Those two cases don't seem like huge restrictions though (there's probably a few more hidden caveats)

Comment: Yes, like old-style classes... ;)